# Generate Event to Azure Event Hub on a file creation in azure DataLake

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid

I have a requirement where I need to send file metadata informations (like file name, file path etc.) to Azure Event Hub/ Azure Event Grid whenever a new file is created into Azure Datalake container.
What would be ideal way to do it? Is there any out of box solution for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer here to filter events [reacting to Blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview#filtering-events) and find some [Tutorials and how-tos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=event-grid-event-schema#tutorials-and-how-tos)

Example- [Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=event-grid-event-schema#:%7E:text=Triggered%20when%20a%20blob%20is%20created%20or%20replaced.-,Specifically,-%2C%20this%20event%20is%20triggered%20when%20clients%20use%20the%20CreateFile) for [Use Azure Event Grid to route Blob storage events to web endpoint (Azure portal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal)